# A group G with order $15$ is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

A group $G$ with order $15$ is simple? There are a theorem for realize it? Thanks for all you help!

Comment: There is a unique group of order $15$, $C_{15}$, which is abelian and hence not simple, for it is not of prime order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many arguments to prove that group of order $15$ is not-simple (and in fact, is cyclic).

I came, few years before, across the following interesting argument, through an exercise from Gallian's "Contemporary Abstract Algebra". (At that time, the exercise taught me- *Very elementary facts can be nicely used to crack some simple statements in Algebra*)

Let $|G|=15$. By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element (subgroup) of order $5$. Let $H$ denote a subgroup of order $5$.

If $K\neq H$ is another subgroup of order $5$, then $K\cap H=1$ (why?), hence 
$$|HK|=\frac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{5\cdot5}{1}>|G|,$$
a contradiction. Hence subgroup of order $5$ is *unique*, hence normal, hence $G$ is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

The cyclic group $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,\ldots,a^{14}\}$ of order $15$ is not simple.  The set $\{e,a^5,a^{10}\}$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Hi, Michael. But Algebra (Fraleigh, pp. 177) says: A finite group G, where |G| = pq (primes), and where p < q, have a subgroup with order q, and is normal in G.

|H| = 15 = 3(5) and 3 < 5, then have only 1 subgroup with order 5 (and is normal).

I am consfuse with your example. Can you help me? Thanks Michael!

Comment: @Mario How is this statement from Fraleigh related to your question or this answer?

Comment: The subset $\{e,a^3,a^6,a^9,a^{12}\}$ is a normal subgroup of order $5$ and index $3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Or one uses Feit-Thompson… `;-)`